# How to use "getActivity()" in fragment using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i want solve this problem.

this java code

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                activity.finish();
            }
```

How I can use this code using kotlin?

```
 val activity: Activity = getActivity()
            activity.finish()
```

when I convert this code to `kotlin` like above code.

`getActivity()` -> get error.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What error? Was a message printed?

Comment: `getActivity()` in kotlin is converted to `activity` property access. So: `activity?.finish()` is enough and remove `val activity: Activity = getActivity()`.

Comment: `activity?.finish()`

Answer (score 6):

For Fragment use `activity` instead of `getActivity`

Answer (score 3):

Getting activity from a fragment in Kotlin is optional (might be null) so the type must be `Activity?` then you have to safecall it like `activity?.finish()` and it won't crash with an NPE if activity is null.

Also, you can use property syntax and just call activity instead of getActivity().

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, when I was new to Kotlin.

In **Java**:

```java
Activity a = getActivity();
if (null != a) {
  a.finish();
}
```

In **Kotlin**:

```kotlin
let a = activity
a?.finish()
```

or just

```kotlin
activity?.finish()
```

### Interoperability between Java and Kotlin

It is clarified in [Calling Java code from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html):

> **Getters and Setters**
>
> Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with `get` and single-argument methods with names starting with `set`) are represented as properties in Kotlin.
> ...
> [Emphasis added]

Accordingly, Java method `getActivity()` will be just a property `activity` in Kotlin.

In addition, the null-check `if (null != a) { ... }` will be just `a?`, which [Gregory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63789526/9298629) has clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin:

```
activity?.finish() // ? operator prevent of NPE
```